# Insert Datas with an prepare PHP SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, post

I will insert POST Variables from an HTML Formular with PHP into a MySQL database.
I can update Tables and I can insert data with a normal SQL query but I want to insert the data with a prepared statement and this doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_GET['aktualisieren'])){
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE frequenz SET benutzer =:benutzer, filiale = :filiale, wetter = :wetter, datum = :datum, uhrzeit = :uhrzeit,
 hg_ger_b = :hg_ger_b, hg_ger_v = :hg_ger_v, hg_zub_b = :hg_zub_b, hg_zub_v = :hg_zub_v, hg_ers_b = :hg_ers_b, hg_ers_v = :hg_ers_v, hg_rep = :hg_rep,
 pr_ger_b = :pr_ger_b, pr_ger_v = :pr_ger_v, pr_zub_b = :pr_zub_b, pr_zub_v = :pr_zub_v, pr_ers_b = :pr_ers_b, pr_ers_v = :pr_ers_v, pr_rep = :pr_rep,
 so_ser = :so_ser, so_mie = :so_mie, so_was = :so_was, so_wer = :so_wer, so_web = :so_web, so_bem = :so_bem WHERE id = :id");
$statement->execute(array('benutzer' => $_POST['benutzer'], 'filiale' =>  $_POST['filiale'], 'wetter' => $_POST['wetter'], 'datum' => $_POST['datum'], 'uhrzeit' => $_POST['uhrzeit'],
 'hg_ger_b' => $_POST['hg_ger_b'], 'hg_ger_v' => $_POST['hg_ger_v'], 'hg_zub_b' => $_POST['hg_zub_b'], 'hg_zub_v' => $_POST['hg_zub_v'], 'hg_ers_b' => $_POST['hg_ers_b'], 'hg_ers_v' => $_POST['hg_ers_v'], 'hg_rep' => $_POST['hg_rep'],
 'pr_ger_b' => $_POST['pr_ger_b'], 'pr_ger_v' => $_POST['pr_ger_v'], 'pr_zub_b' => $_POST['pr_zub_b'], 'pr_zub_v' => $_POST['pr_zub_v'], 'pr_ers_b' => $_POST['pr_ers_b'], 'pr_ers_v' => $_POST['pr_ers_v'], 'pr_rep' => $_POST['pr_rep'],
 'so_ser' => $_POST['so_ser'], 'so_mie' => $_POST['so_mie'], 'so_was' => $_POST['so_was'], 'so_wer' => $_POST['so_wer'], 'so_web' => $_POST['so_web'], 'so_bem' => $_POST['so_bem'], 'id' => $_GET['aktualisieren']));
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?seitenlink=frequenz_erfassen&bearbeiten-erfolgreich='.$_GET['aktualisieren'].'">';
exit;
}

if (!isset($_GET['bearbeiten']) and !isset($_GET['aktualisieren']) and isset($_POST['frequenz-eintragen'])){

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO frequenz (benutzer, filiale, wetter, datum, uhrzeit,
 hg_ger_b, hg_ger_v, hg_zub_b, hg_zub_v, hg_ers_b, hg_ers_v, hg_rep,
 pr_ger_b, pr_ger_v, pr_zub_b, pr_zub_v, pr_ers_b, pr_ers_v, pr_rep,
 so_ser, so_mie, so_was, so_wer, so_web, so_bem) VALUES (:benutzer, :filiale, :wetter, :datum, :uhrzeit,
 :hg_ger_b, :hg_ger_v, :hg_zub_b, :hg_zub_v, :hg_ers_b, :hg_ers_v, :hg_rep,
 :pr_ger_b, :pr_ger_v, :pr_zub_b, :pr_zub_v, :pr_ers_b, :pr_ers_v, :pr_rep,
 :so_ser, :so_mie, :so_was, :so_wer, :so_web, :so_bem)");

$statement->execute(array('benutzer' => $_POST['benutzer'], 'filiale' => $_POST['filiale'], 'wetter' => $_POST['wetter'], 'datum' => $_POST['datum'], 'uhrzeit' => $_POST['uhrzeit'],
 'hg_ger_b' => $_POST['hg_ger_b'], 'hg_ger_v' => $_POST['hg_ger_v'], 'hg_zub_b' => $_POST['hg_zub_b'], 'hg_zub_v' => $_POST['hg_zub_v'], 'hg_ers_b' => $_POST['hg_ers_b'], 'hg_ers_v' => $_POST['hg_ers_v'], 'hg_rep' => $_POST['hg_rep'],
 'pr_ger_b' => $_POST['pr_ger_b'], 'pr_ger_v' => $_POST['pr_ger_v'], 'pr_zub_b' => $_POST['pr_zub_b'], 'pr_zub_v' => $_POST['pr_zub_v'], 'pr_ers_b' => $_POST['pr_ers_b'], 'pr_ers_v' => $_POST['pr_ers_v'], 'pr_rep' => $_POST['pr_rep'],
 'so_ser' => $_POST['so_ser'], 'so_mie' => $_POST['so_mie'], 'so_was' => $_POST['so_was'], 'so_wer' => $_POST['so_wer'], 'so_web' => $_POST['so_web'], 'so_bem' => $_POST['so_bem']));

$neue_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();


echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?seitenlink=frequenz_erfassen&bearbeiten-erfolgreich='.$neue_id.'">';
exit;
}
```

my condition works. I tested this by making an output. I have the database connection in a separate file. Here is the content:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;datenbank','benutzer', 'passwort');
$pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Do you have an Idea why It doesn't work?

Comment: This kind of thing is highly suggestive of a denormalised (and hence suboptimal) design

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: I've set errors to be displayed there (`$pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. The script is simply canceled. The code after the query is not output. I can only see the code before the statement.

Comment: If the script halts execution, you must have a fatal error but have not displayed the error. At the top of your code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always when developing and testing code. You will possibly find that `$pdo` does not contain an active connection, or something else that I am not seeing when I go over all these vars.

Comment: Post more of the surrounding code before this, including where `$pdo` is established.

Comment: Error Reporting is on. The `$pdo` works with my other statements. The SQL-Query with UPDATE and SELECT works. Only the INSERT will not work.

Comment: Is this complete? The PDO DSN should include a dbname= `'mysql:host=localhost;datenbank'`  should have `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=datenbank` . If the connection is in a separate file, is the variable `$pdo` correctly in scope where you execute the insert statement? That is, was this inside a function where `$pdo` is not available?

Comment: The Update of the data works. I also include this in my question.

if I `$ statement-> execute (array ('user' => $ _POST ['user'], ...`
comment out, the rest of the code is also executed.I think the mistake is somewhere there.

Comment: You said you have `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` but the only way execution would halt before that `$statement->execute()` is if an exception was thrown by the `prepare()` and you are not seeing the error. Try wrapping the `$statement = prepare()` in a `try/catch` and `var_dump($pdo->errorInfo())` inside the `catch {}` block.